# Using local variables in function built with haxe macro

Tags: macros, haxe

I have a `LangBuilder` macro class; it's used to build a `langObjects:Map<String, Dynamic>` of texts in various languages at compile time, and inject this structure in classes via `@:build` macro. Every item of the Map has a field for every language supported. So the result is:

```
@:build(LangBuilder.build())
class Lang{}

trace(Lang.langObjects["hello-world"].en); //outputs "Hello World!"
trace(Lang.langObjects["hello-world"].it); //outputs "Ciao Mondo!"
```

This works perfectly, but I thought I could make a cleaner job hiding the `langObjects` structure using a function `getLangText` with arguments the id of the text (e.g. `"hello-world"`) and the language code (e.g. `"it"`).

So I'm trying to add this function to classes:

```
public static function getLangText(id:String, lang:String)
```

Its non-macro version could be expressed as:

```
public static function getLangText(id:String, lang:String){
    var _langObj_id = langObjects[id];
    switch(lang){
        case "it":
            return _langObj_id.it;
        case "en":
            return _langObj_id.en;
    }
    return "Missing Translation";
```

If i translate this function as a macro with this code:

```
var code = macro {
  var _langObj_id = langObjects[$i{"id"}];
  switch($i{"lang"}){
    case "it":
      return _langObj_id.it;
    case "en":
      return _langObj_id.en;
  }
  return "Missing translation";
};

var myFunc:Function = {
  args: [{
    name: "id",
    type: TPath({name: "String", pack: []}),
    meta: null
  },
  {
    name: "lang",
    type: TPath({name: "String", pack: []}),
    meta: null
  }],
  ret: (macro:String),
  expr: macro $code
};

fields.push({
  pos: Context.currentPos(),
  name: "getLangText",
  meta: null,
  kind: FieldType.FFun(myFunc),
  doc: null,
  access: [Access.APublic, Access.AStatic]
});
```

... it works without problems. However I would like to know how it could be written without the `switch`, to make it more flexible and to learn something about haxe macros. I have seen some examples where fields could be accessed in macros with `$p{}` or with `object.$fieldName`. However the haxe manual warns that the second form could be used only for simple identifiers; for example `object.${fieldName}` would not work.

So I try this code:

```
var code = macro {
  var l:String = $i{"lang"};
  var _langObj_id = langObjects[$i{"id"}];
  return _langObj_id.$l;
};
```

The compiler gives an error

> Unknown identifier : l

on the line containing `return _langObj_id.$l;`.

Then i tried to use the `$p{}` reification:

```
var code = macro {
  var _langObj_id = langObjects[$i{"id"}];
  return macro $p{["_langObj_id", $i{"lang"}]};
};
```

But the error is similar:

> Unknown identifier : lang

I can surely change the `langObjects` structure to `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` and then change the code to:

```
var code = macro {
  return macro langObjects[$i{"id"}][$i{"lang"}];
};
```

I think this would work, but now i'm trying to understand why both `_langObj_id.$lang` and `$p{["_langObj_id", $i{"lang"}]}` wouldn't work, and what would be the correct way to access a field in a situation like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the `lang` parameter is not known at compile- / macro-time, so I don't see how you could generate a field access expression like `langObjects["mytext"].en`. At runtime when `getLangText()` is actually called, `lang` could be `"en"`, or anything else. So that would still require a switch-case, if-else-chain or reflection to handle all the possible values.

If instead of using being created by a build macro, `getLangText()` was an expression macro / a `macro function`, the function call would be evaluated at compile-time, and be replaced with the expression it returns. That would allow you to generate the appropriate field access expression based on the parameters. It could look something like this:

```
class Macro {
    public static var langObjects = ["mytext" => {en: "hello", de: "hallo"}];

    public static macro function getLangText(id:String, lang:String) {
        return macro {
            var langObject = Macro.langObjects[$v{id}];
            langObject.$lang;
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Main {
    static function main() {
        trace(Macro.getLangText("mytext", "en"));
        trace(Macro.getLangText("mytext", "de"));
    }
}
```

Compiles to the following on the JS target:

```
Main.main = function() {
    var langObject = Macro.langObjects.get("mytext");
    console.log("source/Main.hx:3:",langObject.en);
    var langObject1 = Macro.langObjects.get("mytext");
    console.log("source/Main.hx:4:",langObject1.de);
};
```

Perhaps that's what you're looking for? Hard to say without knowing what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the question to better explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Using a nested map definitely seems like the more pragmatic approach here... Did you understand the first part of my answer? You can't generate a field access at compile time when you're only going to know what the name of that field is going to be _at runtime_. Both of the reification syntaxes you tried would require `lang` to be a variable _outside of the `code` section of your macro_. Since none exists, you end up with "Unknown identifier".

Comment: I understand that `lang` is not known at build time... So there is no way to access a field dynamically, except through a `switch/if-then-else/reflection` where I list the various conditions?

Comment: Well, there's the usual way of accessing fields dynamically at runtime: Reflection. It's either that or a `switch` (or if-else-chain) with all possible values as you say.

Comment: Your alternative macro where the function is replaced with the actual string at compile time is also neat. Alas I can't use it since I need the language to be changeable at runtime. Maybe I could merge that with the nested map structure...

Comment: Note that it's not actually returning the actual string at compile-time, it just generates the field access expression you wanted in your build macro (updated my answer to make that clearer). But of course that could be done if everything was known at compile time (`id`, `lang` and the data).